# Parallax Algorithm not working on Fixed Element

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, parallax

I have written a simple parallax plugin that has worked fantastically up until now... It works by `translating` the specified element across the X-axis (left and right) and the Y-axis (up and down), as the user scrolls the page.

Up until now, I have only used it on standard (non `position: fixed`) items within the DOM.

However, I am now trying to use it on an element that is within an element that has a `fixed` position and for some reason, my algorithm is returning `0` for every translation. I assume this is something to do with the bounding rectangle but I cannot seem to work it out.

Here is the algorithm:

```
let value = Math.round(((window_position + window_height - (height / 2) - (window_height / 2)) * item.options.speed) + (top * -1 * item.options.speed));
```

And here is the full script snippet:

```
/**
 * Move each of the items based on their parallax
 * properties.
 *
 * @return void
 */
move() {

    let window_height   = window.innerHeight;
    let window_position = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;

    this.items.forEach((item) => {

        let { top, height } = item.element.getBoundingClientRect();

        // This will determine the exact position of the element in
        // the document
        top += window_position;

        // No need to proceed if the element is not in the viewport
        if ((top + height) < window_position || top > (window_position + window_height)) {
            return;
        }

        // Calculate the adjustment
        let value = Math.round(((window_position + window_height - (height / 2) - (window_height / 2)) * item.options.speed) + (top * -1 * item.options.speed));

        // Invert the adjustment for up and left directions
        if (['up', 'left'].includes(item.options.direction)) {
            value = -value;
        }

        // This returns 0, regardless of the window_position
        console.log(top, ((window_position + window_height - (height / 2) - (window_height / 2)) * item.options.speed), (top * -1 * item.options.speed));

        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {

            // Do the CSS adjustment

        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resorted to a dirty fix (still open to suggestions):

```
// Calculate the adjustment
let value = (window_position + window_height - (height / 2) - (window_height / 2)) * item.options.speed;

// If the element is not fixed then adjust the algorithm
if (!item.options.fixed) {
    value += (top * -1 * item.options.speed);
}

value = Math.round(value);
```